# !File.Exists is not working as expected for filenames containing UTF-8 characters

Tags: c#, .net

My console application (C#) is working perfectly for the filenames which don't contain any UTF-8 characters but when the filenames contain any UTF-8 character, my condition if(!File.Exists(destFilePath)) is not working as expected.

I need to delete those files which are only present in the destination but not in the source. When there some special characters in my file name, for example,

**file**

C:\A00000001\20162350775-Étienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Hervé Le Guyader.pdf

**destFilePath**

D:\A00000001\20162350775-Étienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Hervé Le Guyader.pdf

The filename in the above case should not be deleted as both source and destination have the same filename but it did. But for normal filenames, there is no issue. My code sample is as below:

```
public void SynchronizeSourceAndDestination(string dir)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                string destFilePath = file.Replace(BackupDirectory, LookupDirectory);

                if (!File.Exists(destFilePath))
                {
                    // Delete file from Backup
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
            }

            foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                string destinationDirectory = directory.Replace(BackupDirectory, LookupDirectory);

                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(directory, true);
                    continue;
                }
                SynchronizeSourceAndDestination(directory);
            }
        }
```

**Note: The asp.net web application has the setting  globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" in the web.config file. The above code is C# console application to process the files saved by the web application. There is no issue with the filenames in my local machine but when the code is in the server, it is not working.**

Comment: Rename the file replacing the diacritics with E/e & try again to test your assumption, the name is unlikely to be causing a problem. Note that if the length of the path on the server exceeds ~260 characters or there is a permissions problem Exists() will return false.

Comment: @Alex K. The length is only 160 characters and the problem it is giving is because of the two character used in the file name  É and é

Comment: If you use `Directory.GetFiles` on the LookupDirectory, and get the filename you are interested in from that, and then use `==` on that against `file` are they the same or different? _Many characters that **look** the same are in fact different characters._

Comment: What is the value of `dir`? `BackupDirectory`? `LookupDirectory`? `file.Replace(BackupDirectory, LookupDirectory)`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `!File.Exists` rather than `File.Exists`?

Comment: Try also this: `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Path.GetFileName(path)))` on both the paths, do they return the same string? You sure it's not different encoding of the diacritics?

Comment: There's no such thing as "UTF-8 Characters" - if you're using the UTF-8 encoding of unicode, then *all* characters you're working with are UTF-8. I.e. `a` is as much a "UTF-8 character" as `ä`.

Comment: Does filename handling consider combining diacritical marks? Both `"\u00e4"` and `"a\u0308"` looks like ä on the screen but are encoded differently. And the answer is no, those will produce different filenames. I suspect you will want to normalize filename strings.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  ASP.NET Web Application is saving files to a folder on the server and there is one element in web.config file as globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8". I have a console application on the server which is doing some backup related operation. Do I need to any setting in console application app.config in this case?

Comment: I have no idea if those settings impact filename encoding/handling. I'm only saying what I observed, and the two strings I commented above results in separate files, even though the filenames look identical on screen. Actually, my command prompt shows a slight difference in the font of the characters, but I can't see a difference in Windows explorer.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I need to use !File.Exists and you could get more from the code sample I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my solution workable I changed extended ASCII character by pressing É **(Alt + 144)**, é **(Alt + 130)**. I think it was because the file creator did some copy and paste of the characters directly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize

Answer (score 2):

It has probably something to do with the length of the filepath (>260 characters) as the `File.Exists` does work with UTF-8 characters.

I've tested it just a couple of minutes ago with csi.exe, this was the output:

```
C:\Temp>csi
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 2.2.0.61624
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Type "#help" for more information.
> System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\A00000001\\20162350775-Étienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilai
re, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Hervé Le Guyader.pdf")
true
>
```

As you can see, the result is `true`. I've tested this on a Windows 10 machine, Dutch language and have VS2017.2 installed.

--edit--
Just to be complete with the comment below, I've created this console app to test.

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string BackupDirectory = "C:\\A00000001\\";
        private const string LookupDirectory = "C:\\A00000002\\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SynchronizeSourceAndDestination("C:\\A00000001\\");
        }

        public static void SynchronizeSourceAndDestination(string dir)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                string destFilePath = file.Replace(BackupDirectory, LookupDirectory);

                if (!File.Exists(destFilePath))
                {
                    // Delete file from Backup
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
            }

            foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                string destinationDirectory = directory.Replace(BackupDirectory, LookupDirectory);

                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(directory, true);
                    continue;
                }
                SynchronizeSourceAndDestination(directory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the folders `A00000001` and `A00000002` are present on your system and place a file inside both of them with the same name and UTF-8 characters (`20162350775-Étienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Hervé Le Guyader.pdf`).

In my case, no file got deleted because of the `File.Exists` check.

Comment: You are right, it's working fine but in my case, the code sample I provided, I need to take filename from destination folder and need to check whether this filename is present in the source folder.

Comment: I've also tested your situation (`C:\\A00000001\\20162350775-Étienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Hervé Le Guyader.pdf` & destFilePath `C:\\A00000002\\20162350775-Étienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Hervé Le Guyader.pdf`) and still got the expected result. No file was deleted as the File.Exists returns `true`. Also tested it with different paths, just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I just created two folders in the server and its working perfectly with the filename. But it's giving the same problem with filename present in the original folder. I didn't notice any difference in the new folder and original folder.

Comment: Could be permissions, as stated in MSDN: 
`If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.` 

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I also think that it's because of some permission issue as my destination folder is in the dropbox. The program is working perfectly in the other folder than a folder inside the dropbox.

Comment: When I renew the file to 20162350775-Etienne Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1772-1844 a visionary naturalist. Herve Le Guyader.pdf just replacing    É to E and  é to e, the program starts working in dropbox folder as well. Could you please help to figure out why is this happening?

Comment: I don't use Dropbox myself, so can't test, but when searching the web I see there are multiple issues with Dropbox and utf8 files (including names). Strange though if the client application modifies or changes the permissions or file locks in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your characters were probably two characters. A normal E followed by a Combining Diacritical Mark. It just look like the single character but in the string itself it is two characters.

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+0300